# how to restore .mdf database in C# windows application from .bak file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

i am using this coding using smo but nothing happened.

```
        Restore res = new Restore();
        res.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\Shivam.bak", DeviceType.File);
        BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(@"\\hqsqlbkup1\VN\Shivam.bak", DeviceType.File);
        res.Database = "ShivamDb";
        res.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        res.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("Shivam", @"+ System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath +\\Shivam.mdf"));
        res.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("Shivam_log", @"System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + \\Shivam_log.ldf"));

        res.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Restore complited");
```

Comment: Just a try, change double \\ to \ in your path as you are using `@` already.

Comment: @faheemkhan and that will then execute the restore WITHOUT HIM CALLING THE METHOD TO DO IT? Besides - "\\" is how you prefix UNC paths. Failing Windows 101 for powerusers.

Comment: @"+ System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath +\\Shivam.mdf" 
On this line do we needed double slashes with file name?

Comment: @faheemkhan No, but that one line does not inintiate the transfer from a SERVER. The OP has the item at a share on the server hqsqlbkup1. "\\servername\share\" is the way to deal with UNC paths. In this case you do need two backslashes. Your example was in a path. Learn windows, please.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I see you creating a restore, initializing a lot - but where do you tell it to EXECUTE That? Where is the call to SqlRestore to actually EXECUTE the restore?

No, initializing a Restore class (SMO) will not magically execute the Operation without you calling the corresponding method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call SqlRestore or SqlRestoreAsyc methods of Restore class, to restore your database!

in the following link you can find good examples about Backup and Restore operations : http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/